# Laravel response json adds empty curly braces after real response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm sending a json response in a function which is not directly called by a route, so I added the `send()` function like this:

```
return response()->json([
    'key' => 'value'
], 400)->send();
```

This leads to following response in the browser:

```
{"key":"value"}{}
```

Where do these empty curly braces come from? How can I get rid of them because this leads to the frontend not recognising the real response.

The, for the sake of this question, simplified code looks like this:

`routes.php`

```
Route::post('/validate', 'ValidationController@validate');
```

`ValidationController.php`

```
public function validate(Request $request) 
{
    // Does some validation

    $this->saveData($request);
}

private function saveData(Request $request)
{
    // saves the data

    try {
        // Tries something
    } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
        return response()->json([
            'key' => 'value'
        ], 400)->send();
    }

    // saves the data
}
```

Comment: try without `->send()`

Comment: @Hussein this leads to the return statement to be ignored.

Comment: try this:
`$res = ['key' => 'value'];
return response()->json($res);`

Comment: @Hussein no luck either.

Comment: can you post your controller code ?

Comment: Could the `{}` be coming from elsewhere?

Comment: @jrenk The `send` method is not in de [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#json-responses) I think your problem has another origin.

Comment: seems like the `{}` comes from your `validate()` function in your `ValidationController`, can you put more codes on the `validate()` function? we can't replicate your problem as your code right now is working on my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`send()` on a response does not necessarily prevent your code from running further. It just writes the response to the OB. There is nothing in your Controller to prevent further execution (like a `return` would). In fact, it only does that in a FastCGI env, because it calls `fastcgi_finish_request` internally.

If you use Apache your issue is easily reproduced:

```php
response(['test' => 'testdata'])->send();
return response()->json(null);
// --> {"test":"testdata"}{}
```

**Luckily there is also the [`throwResponse()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/ResponseTrait.html#method_throwResponse) helper.** If you **use that instead of `send()`** it will throw the response as an `HttpResponseException`, and thus prevent further code execution (-> potentially additional responses written to OB/output).

---

Some more insight:

I just guessed in your controller where you wrote `// saves the data` in the end you have some kind of `return` that returns a `null`-value.

The naive solutions would be to:

- `exit` after your `send()` - really ugly
- `return` the response to your Controller, check return-value of your method like `instanceof Response` and return it further

`throwResponse` comes in really helpful/convenient instead of such solutions.

Comment: very well said :)

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you for the very well written answer.

Answer (score 0):

`response()` will morph objects and arrays into json automatically. You just need to do:

```
return response([
    'key' => 'value'
], 400)->send();
```

See: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php#L43

Comment: this will not work on OP's `saveData` function as it's not directly called by a route, so *`->send()`* function is needed to send the headers and the content.